# How can I vertically align the bullet in a XAML TreeView HierarchicalDataTemplate?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

When a node in my TreeView has multiple lines, the TreeView bullet gets vertically centered.

**How can I top-align the TreeView bullet?**

[alt text http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/1uh2k8p.png](http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/1uh2k8p.png)

```
<pages:BasePage.Resources>
    <data:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="OutlineTemplate"
        ItemsSource="{Binding OutlineDocumentObjects}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Line}" 
            TextWrapping="Wrap" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Width="600"/>
    </data:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</pages:BasePage.Resources>

<StackPanel Style="{StaticResource StackPanelPageWrapperStyle}">
    <tk:TreeView x:Name="TheTreeView" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding TheOutline.OutlineDocumentObjects}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource OutlineTemplate}">
    </tk:TreeView>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 2):

Good question... of course, it could be done by redefining the template, but it's a pain... (if you want to go that way, extract the template with StyleSnooper or ShowMeTheTemplate and change the `VerticalAlignment` of the `ToggleButton`)

Another way is to inherit `TreeViewItem` and override the `OnApply` method. Since the `ToggleButton` has a name ("Expander") in the default template, you can find it and apply the `VerticalAlignment` you want :

```
public class TopAlignedTreeViewItem : TreeViewItem
{
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        if (Template != null)
        {
            ToggleButton btn = Template.FindName("Expander", this) as ToggleButton;
            if (btn != null)
            {
                btn.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For the `TreeView` to generate `TopAlignedTreeViewItem`s instead of `TreeViewItem`s, you also need to make your own `TreeView` :

```
public class TopAlignedTreeView : TreeView
{
    protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
    {
        return (item is TopAlignedTreeViewItem);
    }

    protected override System.Windows.DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new TopAlignedTreeViewItem();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do I need to reference in my code behind to use Template.FindName?

Comment: nothing, Template is a property of the current instance (this.Template)

Comment: I'm getting: 'System.Windows.Controls.ControlTemplate' does not contain a definition for 'FindName' and no extension method 'FindName' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ControlTemplate' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Ah, you must be using Silverlight... Template.FindName is available only in WPF. So I guess you will have to redefine the template...

Comment: sorry, yes, I'm using silverlight, ok, I'll go that route